# Python, permutation to permuation-index function

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools, factorial

I have some permutations of a list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> perms = list(itertools.permutations([0,1,2,3]))
>>> perms
[(0, 1, 2, 3), (0, 1, 3, 2), (0, 2, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3, 1), (0, 3, 1, 2), (0, 3, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2, 3), (1, 0, 3, 2), (1, 2, 0, 3), (1, 2, 3, 0), (1, 3, 0, 2), (1, 3, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1, 3), (2, 0, 3, 1), (2, 1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 3, 0), (2, 3, 0, 1), (2, 3, 1, 0), (3, 0, 1, 2), (3, 0, 2, 1), (3, 1, 0, 2), (3, 1, 2, 0), (3, 2, 0, 1), (3, 2, 1, 0)]
>>> len(perms)
24
```

What function can I use (without access to the list `perm`) to get the index of an arbitrary permutation, e.g. `(0, 2, 3, 1)` -> `3`?

(You can assume that permuted elements are always an ascending list of integers, starting at zero.)

Hint: The factorial number system may be involved.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

Comment: What you are asking for is [ranking](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Permutations/Rank_of_a_permutation) a permutation. There are many implementations of what you are looking for... just scroll down to the Python section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head I came up with the following, didn't test it thoroughly.

```py
from math import factorial
elements = list(range(4))
permutation = (3, 2, 1, 0)
index = 0
nf = factorial(len(elements))

for n in permutation:
    nf //= len(elements)
    index += elements.index(n) * nf
    elements.remove(n)

print(index)
```

**EDIT:** replaced `nf /= len(elements)` with `nf //= len(elements)`

Comment: You might want to use `nf //= len(elements)` to retain an `int`.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is a challenge, so here is my (recursive) answer:

```
import math
import itertools

def get_index(l):
    # In a real function, there should be more tests to validate that the input is valid, e.g. len(l)>0
    # Terminal case
    if len(l)==1:
        return 0

    # Number of possible permutations starting with l[0]
    span = math.factorial(len(l)-1)

    # Slightly modifying l[1:] to use the function recursively
    new_l = [ val if val < l[0] else val-1 for val in l[1:] ]

    # Actual solution
    return get_index(new_l) + span*l[0]


get_index((0,1,2,3))
# 0
get_index((0,2,3,1))
# 3
get_index((3,2,1,0))
# 23
get_index((4,2,0,1,5,3))
# 529
list(itertools.permutations((0,1,2,3,4,5))).index((4,2,0,1,5,3))
# 529
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own function. Something like this would work

```
import math

def perm_loc(P):

    N = len(P)
    assert set(P) == set(range(N))

    def rec(perm):
        nums = set(perm)
        if not perm:
            return 0
        else:
            sub_res = rec(perm[1:])                  # Result for tail of permutation
            sub_size = math.factorial(len(nums) - 1) # How many tail permutations exist
            sub_index = sorted(nums).index(perm[0])  # Location of first element in permutaiotn
                                                     # in the sorted list of number
            return sub_index * sub_size + sub_res

    return rec(P)
```

The function that does all the work is `rec`, with perm_loc just serving as a wrapper around it. Note that this algorithm is based on the nature of the permutation algorithm that `itertools.permutation` happens to use.

The following code tests the above function. First on your sample, and then on all permutations of `range(7)`:

```
print perm_loc([0,2,3,1]) # Print the result from the example

import itertools

def test(N):
    correct = 0
    perms = list(itertools.permutations(range(N)))
    for (i, p) in enumerate(perms):
        pl = perm_loc(p)
        if i == pl:
            correct += 1
        else:
            print ":: Incorrect", p, perms.index(p), perm_loc(N, p)
    print ":: Found %d correct results" % correct

test(7) # Test on all permutations of range(7)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from math import factorial

def perm_to_permidx(perm):
    # Extract info
    n = len(perm)
    elements = range(n)
    # "Gone"s will be the elements of the given perm
    gones = []
    # According to each number in perm, we add the repsective offsets
    offset = 0
    for i, num in enumerate(perm[:-1], start=1):
        idx = num - sum(num > gone for gone in gones)
        offset += idx * factorial(n - i)
        gones.append(num)
    return offset

the_perm = (0, 2, 3, 1)
print(perm_to_permidx(the_perm))
# 3
```

Explanation: All permutations of a given range can be considered as a groups of permutations. So, for example, for the permutations of `0, 1, 2, 3` we first "fix" 0 and permute rest, then fix 1 and permute rest, and so on. Once we fix a number, the rest is again permutations; so we again fix a number at a time from the remaining numbers and permute the rest. This goes on till we are left with one number only. Every level of fixing has a corresponding `(n-i)!` permutations.

So this code finds the "offsets" for each level of permutation. The `offset` corresonds to where the given permutation starts when we fix numbers of `perm` in order. For the given example of `(0, 2, 3, 1)`, we first look at the first number in the given `perm` which is 0, and figure the offset as 0. Then this goes to `gones` list (we will see its usage). Then, at the next level of permutation we see 2 as the fixing number. To calculate the offset for this, we need the "order" of this 2 among the remaining three numbers. This is where `gones` come into play; if an already-fixed and considered number (in this case 0) is less than the current fixer, we subtract 1 to find the new order. Then offset is calculated and accumulated. For the next number 3, the new order is `3 - (1 + 1) = 1` because both previous fixers 0 and 2 are at the "left" of 3.

This goes on till the last number of the given `perm` since there is no need to look at it; it will have been determined anyway.